# Pulling all information left of a column from multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I have a workbook (Google Sheets) where three different sheets have three unique forms that feed into them.

The titles of each sheet is each respective employee's name and the number of columns vary within each form however the final column in each is titled "Week".

I wish to add a fourth "Week" sheet where you can pull down the employee name (same as sheet name) and the appropriate week and find that employee's entry for that week.

The sheets look a little like this:

Sheet 1: EmployeeA

```
J1  J2        Week
Yes Maybe     2    
Yes Definetly 3
```

Sheet 2: EmployeeB

```
Q1  Q2     Q3        Week
No Strong Maybe      3
```

Sheet 3: EmployeeC

```
L1  L2     L3        L4     Week
Yes Strong Maybe     Happy  2    
Yes Weak   Definetly Happy  3
No  Weak   Never     Sad    4
```

So I would like to create a fourth sheet that looks like this:

```
Employee:  _______
Week:      _______

**CONTENT FROM THE ROW WITH THAT WEEK
```

This would be an easy VLOOKUP however because there are differing amount of columns I am unsure how to approach

I have the Employee/Week options as pull-downs.

As an example, this is how Sheet4 would look

```
Employee:  EmployeeC
Week:      2

L1  L2     L3        L4     Week
Yes Strong Maybe     Happy  2
```

Note that this also should include the titles of the table it's pulling from, which again is different for each sheet.

Edit: Here is the link to the workbook; this has all the information that will be used, with edited content
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qMTc2x1vh47KfXfBfsj70ZliwKNRTzOvjYs6N5hIKZ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 done! This is the full workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure you describe in your question, entering this into your Summary sheet should work:

```
={INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1:R1C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE);
  FILTER(INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C1:C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE), 
         INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)&":C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0), FALSE)=$B$2)}
```

[View Answer Demo Here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcXnncMOMloZ38DUExzGtUZO94MeozB0nATxyxR_l4E/edit#gid=1976623688)

### Explanation

- `$B$1` is your selected Employee value, which refers to a sheet name.
- `$B$2` is your selected week number, which is used to filter results.
- `INDIRECT($B$1&"!"...)` lets us reference a range, including which sheet it's on,  dynamically.
- `MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)` finds the index of the column in the selected sheet that contains the "Week" column.
- `INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1:R1C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE)` pulls in the headings.
- `FILTER(INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C1:C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE), 
       INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)&":C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0), FALSE)=$B$2)` pulls in all rows whose Week value matches the week specified.

### Updated Answer for [Actual Workbook's structure](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qMTc2x1vh47KfXfBfsj70ZliwKNRTzOvjYs6N5hIKZ4/edit#gid=566126759)

- Replace `$B$2` with `INT(REGEXEXTRACT($E$1, "^Week (\d+)"))` which extracts the week number from your freetext week description (ex: `"Week 4: Week of September 2 to September 8"` => `4`).
- Replace `MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)` with `MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)`, as "Reporting Week" is the heading of the target Week column in each Employee's data sheet.

```
={INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1:R1C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE);
  FILTER(INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C1:C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE), 
         INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)&":C"&MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0), FALSE)=INT(REGEXEXTRACT($E$1, "^Week (\d+)")))}
```

---

## Alternative Answer for selecting columns to left *and* right of target column

```
={{INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1:R1C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE),
   INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)+1)&":R1C"&COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1")), FALSE)};
  FILTER({INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C1:C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE),
          INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&(MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)+1)&":C"&COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1")), FALSE)},
         INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)&":C"&MATCH("Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0), FALSE)=$B$2)}
```

[View Alternative Demo Here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcXnncMOMloZ38DUExzGtUZO94MeozB0nATxyxR_l4E/edit#gid=1922486646)

For the actual workbook, this is equivalent to:

```
={{INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1:R1C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE),
   INDIRECT($B$1&"!R1C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)+1)&":R1C"&COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1")), FALSE)};
  FILTER({INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C1:C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)-1), FALSE),
          INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&(MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)+1)&":C"&COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1")), FALSE)},
         INDIRECT($B$1&"!R2C"&MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0)&":C"&MATCH("Reporting Week", INDIRECT($B$1&"!1:1"), 0), FALSE)=INT(REGEXEXTRACT($E$1, "^Week (\d+)")))}
```

Comment: This is great, however I tried copy and pasting it in the doc I created above; it only returns the first row not the second

Comment: @JohnnyThomas I made the sheet before you shared your doc -- let me take a quick look and update accordingly!

Comment: Okay no sweat, I appreciate it; I also wanted to note that I accidentally put the Week column earlier in some sheets than the last one; is there any way to return the row the selected "week" value appears as opposed to just what is to the right? No problem if not, I'll just fix the problem sheets since it's a different request than what I asked

Comment: @JohnnyThomas looks like your doc doesn't have the week # dropdown like you described. My demo expects you to have a week number selected in cell `$B$2`. To fix, you can either put a number in `$B$2`, or update my references to $B$2 to match where you intend to have it. FWIW, you can also extract it from the text you currently have in E1 -- try replacing my references to `$B$2` with `INT(REGEXEXTRACT($E$1, "^Week (\d+)"))`

Comment: YES! I didn't need the last part, just changed $B$2 to $E$2 Thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyThomas updated answer to pull Week dynamically from text like you had it in your doc. Should be able to update my script to work for your "not-just-to-the-right" if you give me a minute, if it's something you still need?

Comment: great; if you could include that as a separate alternative so people who see this in the future aren't confused that would be great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198613/discussion-between-kate-and-johnny-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

alternative:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({
 INDIRECT(B1&"!"&ADDRESS(1, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(
 INDIRECT(B1&"!A:A")), MATCH("Week", 
 INDIRECT(B1&"!1:1"), 0)-1)), 
 INDIRECT(B1&"!"&ADDRESS(1, MATCH("Week", 
 INDIRECT(B1&"!1:1"), 0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(
 INDIRECT(B1&"!A:A")), MATCH("Week", 
 INDIRECT(B1&"!1:1"), 0)))}, "where Col"&MATCH("Week", 
 INDIRECT(B1&"!1:1"), 0)&" = "&B2, 1), ROWS(A:A), COUNTA(
 INDIRECT(B1&"!1:1"))-1)
```

[image: 0]